# Set security groups to an ALB aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to set a few security groups to my ALB.
This is code I wrote:

```
def set_alb_security_group(cfd_sg):
    global ALB_ARN
    
    client = boto3.client('elb', 'eu-central-1')
    result = client.apply_security_groups_to_load_balancer(
        LoadBalancerName='Jenkins-ELB',
        SecurityGroups=['sg-088257e3c09954802', 'sg-0f99e3a27f7ceb393', 'sg-0c262b4c866c7258a']
    )
    logging.info(result)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and here it is the code I get:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (LoadBalancerNotFound) when calling the ApplySecurityGroupsToLoadBalancer operation: There is no ACTIVE Load Balancer named 'Jenkins-ELB'",
  "errorType": "AccessPointNotFoundException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda.py\", line 44, in lambda_handler\n    update_security_groups(cf_ranges)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda.py\", line 58, in update_security_groups\n    rangeToUpdate = get_security_groups_for_update(client, True)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda.py\", line 245, in get_security_groups_for_update\n    return create_security_groups(client, response)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda.py\", line 227, in create_security_groups\n    set_alb_security_group(created_sgs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda.py\", line 279, in set_alb_security_group\n    result = client.apply_security_groups_to_load_balancer(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 386, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 705, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

I am 100% sure I have the load balancer with exact this name.
What I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your client is set up to work with [Classic Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/load-balancer-types.html), not Application Load Balancers as you're using `elb` as the client type.**

`client = boto3.client('elb', 'eu-central-1')`

[Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elb.html):

> This reference covers the 2012-06-01 API, which supports **Classic Load Balancers**

---

To create a client which works with Application Load Balancers, **you need to provide `elbv2` as the client type**:

`client = boto3.client('elbv2, 'eu-central-1')`

[Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html):

> This reference covers the following load balancer types:
>
> **Application Load Balancer** - Operates at the application layer (layer 7) and supports HTTP and HTTPS.
>
> Network Load Balancer - Operates at the transport layer (layer 4) and supports TCP, TLS, and UDP.
>
> Gateway Load Balancer - Operates at the network layer (layer 3).

Answer (score 1):

You are using "elb" as a client, which is used just for "Classic" load balancers. Since you're using ALB, you should use "elbv2" as a client